# How do we implement this relationship?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have to build my E/R model.
I have 3 entities. Hero, Family_Hero, SuperPower.
Hero is name of the hero. (id, description) (eg. "Superman", "Batman")
Family_Hero is the family of Hero (eg. "Superman" and "Batman" are in the family "Flying heroes")
The relation between Hero to Family_Hero is Many-To-One. (One Hero belong to only one Family_Hero. One Family_Hero has many Hero).
Superpower is the name of the power. (eg. "Flying", "SuperStrenght", "Superpunch")

I want a relation between superpower and both hero and family_hero.
I want that a family_hero bring basic superpower, while relation with hero bring specific superpower.

For example.
"Batman" and "Superman" is the family "Flying hero". Every "Flying Heroes" has basic super power like "Fly" and "Super Strenght".
"Batman" has also "Superpunch" power.
Every time I create a "Flying heroes" hero it automatically get "Fly" and "Super Strenght".

How can I create my model in sql.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for this complication? Every superhero has a set of superpowers, which intersects with possibly many other sets (belonging to other heroes). Which of these intersections you bring into "hero family" looks to be pretty arbitrary. Why not just associate superheroes with superpowers directly?

Comment: I have a lot of heroes, and a few families. Superpower very depend on family. So Family brings only basic superpower, while the superpowers of the hero is a plus on the family superpower...

Answer (score 1):

Below is the model more or less. You would have to select distinct superpowers for hero and family or use triggers to copy family powers to hero powers. Or strictly use functions for insert and delete that do that job, rather then using insert and delete Statements directly.

**family_hero**

```
  id_family_hero   PK
  name
```

**hero**

```
  id_hero          PK 
  name
  id_family_hero   FK
```

**superpower**

```
  id_superpower    PK
  name
```

**family_hero_superpower**

```
  id_family_hero   FK
  id_superpower    FK
```

**hero_superpower**

```
  id_hero          FK
  id_superpower    FK
```

**query**

```
select
  h.name as hero_name,
  fh.name as family_name,
  group_concat(distinct s.name) as superpowers
from hero h
join family_hero fh using (id_family_hero)
join hero_superpower hs using (id_hero)
join family_hero_superpower fhs using (id_family_hero)
join superpower s on s.id_superpower in (hs.id_superpower, fhs.id_superpower)
group by hero_name, family_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Family_Hero](
[Id] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[Family] [varchar](50) NULL)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Superpower](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[Skill] [varchar](50) NULL)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SuperpowersInFamilys](
[FamilyId] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[SuperpowerId] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Hero](
[Id] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[Hero] [varchar](50) NULL,
[FamilyId] [int] NULL)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Hero]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Hero_Family_Hero] FOREIGN     KEY([FamilyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Family_Hero] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Hero] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Hero_Family_Hero]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SuperpowersInFamilys]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT     [FK_SuperpowersInFamilys_Family_Hero_FamilyId] FOREIGN KEY([FamilyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Family_Hero] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SuperpowersInFamilys] CHECK CONSTRAINT     [FK_SuperpowersInFamilys_Family_Hero_FamilyId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SuperpowersInFamilys]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT     [FK_SuperpowersInFamilys_Superpower_Id] FOREIGN KEY([SuperpowerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Superpower] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SuperpowersInFamilys] CHECK CONSTRAINT     [FK_SuperpowersInFamilys_Superpower_Id]
GO
```

And for your reference, the graph should looks like:
[image]